# Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: xcode, swift, null, option-type

I'm working with contacts in my app, user can choose a contact name…
but if first name or last name being empty, I will get this common error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I know my question maybe duplicate, but I have read some articles but I couldn't find out how to solve mine.

Here is my code:

```
let firstName: ABMultiValueRef? =
        ABRecordCopyValue(person,
            kABPersonFirstNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef


        let lastName: ABMultiValueRef? =
        ABRecordCopyValue(person,
            kABPersonLastNameProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef

        titleField.text = ("\(firstName) \(lastName)")
```

I want to fill textfield anyway.

**EDIT:**

I have found this solution from related question:

```
 var name:String = ""
        if let first = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            name += first
        }
        if let last  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String {
            name += last
        }
        titleField.text =  name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sprinkle some `?`'s around to account for the `nil`, e.g.,

```
let firstName: ABMultiValueRef? =
        ABRecordCopyValue(person,
            kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? ABMultiValueRef
```

You should also be prepared for the possibility than `firstName` may be `nil`, and, e.g., use optional binding with `if let firstName: ABMultiValueRef = …`, and put any code relying on `firstName` in the then-branch of the `if`. The whole thing would look something like:

```
if let firstName: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
        kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? ABMultiValueRef,
       lastName: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person,
        kABPersonLastNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? ABMultiValueRef {
    titleField.text = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
} else {
    titleField.text = "" // <- handle the failure case?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if((let first = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String) && (let last  = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty)?.takeRetainedValue() as? String)) {

    titleField.text = ("\(firstName) \(lastName)")

}
```